# Parsing orphaned XML children

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml.etree

I've been trying to parse the following XML file using xml.etree: [Bills.xml](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/32bd046744c33f59c599976caab57bb7)

This is the simple python source: [xml.py](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/56beec8378b6a440d52d56702d566d73)

I'm able to successfully print the child under BILLFIXED using the for loop. The result of which is as under:

> - 1-Apr-2017 [Registered Creditor] 1
> - 1-Apr-2017 [Registered Creditor] 58

However, as you can see in the XML certain orphaned child, BILLCL BILLOVERDUE BILLDUE which must logically be under BILLFIXED are not taken into consideration when outputting the XML as we are finding all the elements under BILLFIXED using the following code:

```
billfixed = dom.findall('BILLFIXED')
```

Is there any way to include the BILLCL, BILLDUE and BILLOVERDUE to be included under their respective listing? I'm unable to think of any logic that could help me consider those orphaned children to be treated as the sub children of BILLFIXED.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can control the XML's creation you should change this. If you have to deal with it you can use XQuery methods [like these](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/c0033.html#c0041). But this depends on the XQuery tool you are using. If you can be sure that the elements are there in any case, you might read them out numbered and join them with these numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine was able to answer and help me with the following code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dba333b6c6342d13d21fd8c0781692cb

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree


dom = ElementTree.parse('bills.xml')

billfixed = dom.findall('BILLFIXED')
billcl = dom.findall('BILLCL')
billdue = dom.findall('BILLDUE')
billoverdue = dom.findall('BILLOVERDUE')

for fixed, cl, due, overdue in zip(billfixed, billcl, billdue, billoverdue) :
    party = fixed.find('BILLDATE').text
    date = fixed.find('BILLREF').text
    ref = fixed.find('BILLPARTY').text


    print(' * {} [{}] {} + {} + {} + {}'.format(
       party, ref, date, cl.text, due.text, overdue.text
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip`:

```
for bill_fixed_node, bill_cl in zip(root.findall('BILLFIXED'), root.iter('BILLCL')):
    print(bill_fixed_node)
    print(bill_cl.text)

# <Element 'BILLFIXED' at 0x07905120>
# 600.00
# <Element 'BILLFIXED' at 0x079052D0>
# 10052.00
```

But it would probably be better to fix the structure of the XML file if you have control over it.

Comment: Thank you! A friend of mine was able to provide me the right direction using zip. I've posted the answer.